# I want my Discord bot to answer "abc def" when someone writes "abc" but it keeps spamming "abc def"

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I am writing a Discord bot using Python and this is one of the commands.

I want the bot to answer "abc def" every time I write "abc" but it keeps spamming "abc def".

```
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_message(self, message):
        if "abc" in message.content.lower():
            await message.channel.send('abc def')
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because the message you are sending contains the text you are comparing to in the if-statement, which leads to recursion: the listener is invoked, sends a message, and is invoked again because of its own message, which in turn makes it send the message, which invokes it again and so on.

You could fix it by checking if the sender of `message` equals the bot user and only sending the message if not.

Comment: i tried to by doing this:

botid = 


    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_message(self, message):
        if message.author.id != botid:
            if "סתיו" in message.content.lower():
                # in this case don't respond with the word "Tutorial" or you will call the on_message event recursively
                await message.channel.send('סתיו טוראל ')
but it said "botid" is not defined

Comment: @tal code is unreadable in comments, especially for a whitespace oriented language like python. Edit the code into your initial question so it can be readable.